# ¿Cómo meter una tabla en el siguiente fragmento?

Tags: php, html, html-tabla

Os comento el problema, me veo en la obligación de hacer un `echo implode` para que me muestre el contenido del *array* (debería ponerlo en **css** los **styles**, pero eso lo dejo para lo último):

```
<p class="pminfo" style="font-size: 0.85em; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;background-color: #E7F5FB; margin-top: -3px">';
    echo implode(', ', $context['list_binding_13']);
    echo '</p>';
```

Como podéis ver, por hacer el `echo implode` me veo en la obligación de hacer dos `echo`, uno para el inicio de la etiqueta, y otro para marcar el cierre.

El problema es que no me admite `<table`, pues si lo pongo, no lo tiene en cuenta (lo tiene en cuenta, pero no encierra el `echo implode`; se va abajo).

Pretendo hacer una **tabla** *con 1 fila y 2 columnas*, en la cual el `echo implode` sea la *2º columna*, y una imagen que quiera poner ocupe la *1º columna*.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

El lenguaje usado es `PHP`, y esto se pondría en un `template` siguiendo el **modelo-vista-controlador**

Comment: Espera espera, metiendo datos, como debiese verse entonces el resultado, que esperas obtener.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber entendido que quieres esto:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="pminfo" style="font-size: 0.85em; font-family: verdana, sans-serif;background-color: #E7F5FB; margin-top: -3px">';
    echo implode(', ', $context['list_binding_13']);
    echo '</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table';
```

Es decir, debes agregar la definición de tabla, la fila, la primera columna con la imagen y el inicio de la segunda columna **antes** del elemento `<p`.

Y posteriormente, justo a continuación de `</p>` cerrarlo todo tal como ves en el código que he puesto.

¿Es eso lo que quieres? Recuerda poner la url de la imagen en el campo `src=` del elemento `<img`.